# View Uses Whole Table When Queried Using Joins Or Variables

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression

I have a view that builds a department structure through recursion.

```
Department:
Cust(fk) Department_Id(pk) Name
1        1                 DeptA
1        2                 DeptB
1        3                 DeptC
1        4                 DeptC2
1        5                 DeptQ

Department Map:
Department_Id  ParentId
1              null
2              1
3              2
4              2
5              1
```

Please forgive the table structure. I know the two tables can be combined, but it's old design that would be hard to alter. The view builds up the hierarchy so we can group them together.

```
Department View Output (vwDepartmentStructure):
Cust BottomId DepartmentId DepartmentName Position
1    1        1            DeptA          1

1    2        2            DeptB          1
1    2        1            DeptA          2

1    3        3            DeptC          1
1    3        2            DeptB          2
1    3        1            DeptA          3

1    4        4            DeptC2         1
1    4        2            DeptB          2
1    4        1            DeptA          3

1    5        5            DeptQ          1
1    5        1            DeptA          2
```

The view itself comes back pretty fast with the large amount of data we have in the system. The trouble comes in when I try to query this view using the BottomId (indexed field) and a non-hard-coded value.

This returns very quick (less than a second):

```
select * from vwDepartmentStructure s where s.BottomId = 4
```

However, this is a different story:

```
Declare @bottomId int = 4
select * from vwDepartmentStructure s where s.BottomId = @bottomId
```

This runs at about 15 - 20 seconds based on the data in our system. I looked at the execution plan and it says it's grabbing all the possible variations (the entire view result) and filters it at the end; whereas, the hard-coded value only  retrieves for that BottomId.  This is also slow when I try to join the view with other tables (it's where I found the issue).

```
select * from person p 
inner join vwDepartmentStructure s on s.Cust = p.CustomerId and s.BottomId = s.Department
where p.Id = 123
```

I did read something about how hard coded values perform better due to the execution plan being built up, but variables change the execution plan to make it more dynamic but slower.  What throws me for a loop, however, is this query runs equally fast to the hard-coded one:

```
Declare @customer int = 1
select * from vwDepartmentStructure s where s.Cust = @customer and s.BottomId = 4
```

Is there anything that I can do to make it recognize the variable value for the BottomId before grabbing the full table?

UPDATE
Here's the CTE:

```
USE [TESTDB]
GO

DROP VIEW [dbo].[vwTestRouting]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTestRouting]
AS
    WITH allDept (Cust, BottomDeptId, Position, DeptId, Manager_Key, MaxApproval, ParentId)
    AS(
        SELECT d.CustomerKey, d.DeptId, 1, d.DeptId, d.ManagerKey, d.MaxApproval, dm.ParentId
           from Department d
           inner join DepartmentMap dm on d.DeptId = dm.DeptId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ad.Cust, ad.BottomDeptId, ad.Position + 1, d.DeptId, d.ManagerKey, d.MaxApproval, dm.ParentId
           from allDept ad 
           inner join Department d on d.DeptId = ad.ParentId
           inner join DepartmentMap dm on d.DeptId = dm.DeptId
    )
    select * from allDept;

GO
```

Comment: can you please post your `create view` script

Comment: Views can be expensive.  I'll often opt for a Table-Valued Function ... standardized output, parameter driven, easy to incorporate within other queries and cross applies.

Comment: But the last query has a hard coded s.BottomId = 4.  The s.Cust = @customer is not going to slow it down.   Are you saying the entire view return faster then just returning a single `s.BottomId = @bottomId` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to compare both query plan with below query.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes (plan_handle)
```

Hopefully, your problem will be resolve with using 
**`SET ARITHABORT ON`**

`.